# Fatal Error when calling getChildrenCategories on a Flat Category Collection in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Basically, I'm trying to display a list of the URL, thumbnail, and name of the top categories in our Magento store in a (core/template) block on our home page. We're using Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2, though I think the code referenced would also apply to the Community Edition.

To Load the Categories I'm using the following:

```
/**
 * Parent Category of store
 * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
 */
$_parent_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);

/**
 * Resource Model that will allow us to load the Categories.
 * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category
 */
$_resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category');

/**
 * Collection of Child Categories
 * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection
 */
 $_categories = $_resource->getChildrenCategories($_parent_category);
```

Everything works fine until I switch to flat tables (change System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend -> Us Flat Catalog Category) to "Yes"

Once I do that, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat_Collection::joinUrlRewrite() in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php
```

I reindexed, flushed all caches, etc..

**Is this a bug in the core code base or simply an execution error on my part?**

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the category model (`catalog/category`) uses different resource models for different settings of `Use Flat Catalog Category` and you are always using `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category');`.  If the flat categories are enabled the resource model should be `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_flat');`.
In order not to be bothered by this I recommend using

```
$_parent_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
$_categories = $_parent_category->getChildrenCategories();
```

and let Magento decide what resource model to use.

Comment: Ah, of course. I feel like an idiot. Thanks for your help, Marius.

Comment: Im getting this error with native calls from Mage_Catalog_Block_list on catalog page